# How to take the total sum of all objects within an object?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the total sum of all parts in a container.  The way I am doing now, sum(weight), will only grab the first weight of the first part in the container.  I want to grab all part weights where the container number is the same.  There are many different container numbers in the table.  I want the statement to work with different container numbers, and only insert the value in the row of the first occurrence of the container number.

http://s33.postimg.org/3t63t83hr/sumweight.png

Each part has a weight in the above.  I want to tally those weights for each container number and sum it up on the first row like shown.

```
,(case when mu.master_unit_no is null
then c.Gross_weight
when mu.master_unit_no is not null
then sum(c.Gross_weight)+mut.tare_weight
end)
as 'Weight in LBS'
```

Right now I have this query but it returns just the first part weight + the tare weight.  I want to grab the sum of all the parts for the container.

```
/* I-Dashboards Shipping Report */
/* ROTW 11-21-2015 */
select
p.part_no  AS 'Part_Number'
,p.name AS 'Description'
,c.serial_no as 'S#'
,c.quantity AS 'Qty'
,cp.customer_part_No as 'F_NUMBER'
--,cast(mut.length AS varchar) + 'X' + Cast(mut.width as varchar) + 'X' + Cast(mut.Height as varchar) as 'dim MU'
,(CASE when mut.length is null
then 0
else cast(mut.length as int) end) as 'M_LEN' 
,(CASE when mut.width is null
then 0
else cast(mut.width as int) end) As 'M_WD' 
,(CASE when mut.height is null
then 0
else cast(mut.Height as int) end) AS 'M_HT'
,cast(pct.cube_length AS INT) as 'S_LEN'
,cast(pct.cube_width AS INT) AS  'S_WD'
,cast(pct.cube_height AS INT) AS 'S_HT'
,mut.tare_Weight as 'M_Tare_lbs'
,c.Gross_weight as 'Net_Wt_lbs'
,mu.master_unit_no as 'M Number'
,g.Booking_No as 'Booking_HAWB_Num'
,concat(g.cargo_container_no, '-', g.dock_code) as 'Container_ID'
,g.outbound_scac_code AS 'Carrier'

,concat(cast(pct.cube_length as int), 'x', cast(pct.cube_width as int), 'x',     cast(pct.cube_height as int)) as 'BOX_DIMS_INCHES'

,(case when row_number() over (partition by mu.master_unit_no order by mu.master_unit_no) = 1
then concat(cast(mut.length as int), 'x', cast(mut.width as int), 'x',        cast(mut.Height as int))
when mu.master_unit_no is null
then ''
end)
as 'PALLET_DIMS_INCHES'

,(case when g.booking_container_type_key = 6 THEN
'DIRECT'
when g.booking_container_type_key = 5 THEN
'AIR'
else 'CEVA-Ocean'
end) as 'Shipment Type'

,CASE
--WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY     mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
--then (select sum((pct.cube_length*0.0254)*(pct.cube_width*0.0254)*    (pct.cube_height*0.0254))
--from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_key = mu.master_unit_key)
when mu.master_unit_no is null
then (pct.cube_length*0.0254)*(pct.cube_width*0.0254)*  (pct.cube_height*0.0254) 
end as 'CBM'

,select c.*, CASE
       WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY     mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
       THEN **(**select SUM(c.Gross_weight)+mut.tare_weight 
       from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_no =   mu.master_unit_no**)** END AS 'Total Weight'


from part_v_container c
```

I'm trying to take the total sum of all the parts gross weight in a m number + the tare weight for that m number and store is as total weight.

Comment: Please don't describe your issue in words, show table structure, sample data, queries you've attempted, and an expected result.

Comment: Your image is a broken link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Siyual said, add tables to help better our understanding.  Until then I believe I have most of what you want.

Your table probably looks something like...

```
part_id    container_ id    Weight
-------    -------------    ------
1          a                5
2          a                5
3          b                99
4          a                3
5          c                99
```

And you probably want a result like (example using container_id = a)...

```
Weight 
------
13
```

Try this...

```
SELECT SUM(Weight) FROM someTable WHERE container_id = someContainer
```

In the case of the result example I gave I would do...

```
SELECT SUM(Weight) FROM someTable WHERE container_id = 'a'
```

I am not fully sure on what you mean by your last part **"only insert the value in the row of the first occurrence of the container number"**.  Why would you want this specifically?

**EDIT 1**

The final result should not have multiple container_id though.  I did the following...

My table...

[image]

```
SELECT t1.container_id, SUM(t1.weight) FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_1 t2 ON t1.part_id = t2.part_id GROUP BY t1.container_id
```

Result was...

[image]

**EDIT 2**

It took me a while but I think I got it :)

Table:

[image]
[image]

Query:

```
SELECT t.*, CASE 
            WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Container ORDER BY t.Container)) = 1 
            THEN (SELECT SUM(t2.Weight) FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.Container = t.Container) 
            ELSE 0 END AS 'Total Weight' 
            FROM table1 t GROUP BY t.Container, t.Part, t.Weight
```

Results:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

This was your original...

```
select c.*, CASE
           WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
           THEN select SUM(c.Gross_weight)+mut.tare_weight 
           from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_no = mu.master_unit_no END AS 'Total Weight'
```

This is what I would change (surrounded by two asterix on both sides EX: ** A **)...

```
select c.*, CASE
           WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
           THEN **(**select SUM(c.Gross_weight)+mut.tare_weight 
           from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_no = mu.master_unit_no**)** END AS 'Total Weight'
```

You need the parenthesis because the code doesn't know where the end belongs to otherwise.  The parenthesis allows SQL to know that the end belongs to the case statement.  I also am not sure where the mu. and mut. come from.  It seems like they belong to a different table that you never reference here?

I am not sure if you added it but after 'Total Weight' you are missing

```
 from someTable group by (all things that are in your select aka things that will be output need to be here...see my previous example for a better understanding)
```

If you want, on your original question you can post screen shots of exactly what your tables look like (or manually create it) so I can use the names you use accurately and make it more easily understandable by you :)

**EDIT 4**

```
/* I-Dashboards Shipping Report */
/* ROTW 11-21-2015 */
select
p.part_no  AS 'Part_Number'
,p.name AS 'Description'
,c.serial_no as 'S#'
,c.quantity AS 'Qty'
,cp.customer_part_No as 'F_NUMBER'
--,cast(mut.length AS varchar) + 'X' + Cast(mut.width as varchar) + 'X' + Cast(mut.Height as varchar) as 'dim MU'
,(CASE when mut.length is null
then 0
else cast(mut.length as int) end) as 'M_LEN' 
,(CASE when mut.width is null
then 0
else cast(mut.width as int) end) As 'M_WD' 
,(CASE when mut.height is null
then 0
else cast(mut.Height as int) end) AS 'M_HT'
,cast(pct.cube_length AS INT) as 'S_LEN'
,cast(pct.cube_width AS INT) AS  'S_WD'
,cast(pct.cube_height AS INT) AS 'S_HT'
,mut.tare_Weight as 'M_Tare_lbs'
,c.Gross_weight as 'Net_Wt_lbs'
,mu.master_unit_no as 'M Number'
,g.Booking_No as 'Booking_HAWB_Num'
,concat(g.cargo_container_no, '-', g.dock_code) as 'Container_ID'
,g.outbound_scac_code AS 'Carrier'

,concat(cast(pct.cube_length as int), 'x', cast(pct.cube_width as int), 'x',     cast(pct.cube_height as int)) as 'BOX_DIMS_INCHES'

,(case when row_number() over (partition by mu.master_unit_no order by mu.master_unit_no) = 1
then concat(cast(mut.length as int), 'x', cast(mut.width as int), 'x',        cast(mut.Height as int))
when mu.master_unit_no is null
then ''
end)
as 'PALLET_DIMS_INCHES'

,(case when g.booking_container_type_key = 6 THEN
'DIRECT'
when g.booking_container_type_key = 5 THEN
'AIR'
else 'CEVA-Ocean'
end) as 'Shipment Type'

,(case when row_number() over (partition by mu.master_unit_no order by     mu.master_unit_no) = 1
then (pct.cube_length*0.0254)*(pct.cube_width*0.0254)*(pct.cube_height*0.0254) 
when mu.master_unit_no is null
then (pct.cube_length*0.0254)*(pct.cube_width*0.0254)*  (pct.cube_height*0.0254) 
end)
as 'CBM'

,CASE
       WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY     mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
       THEN (SELECT SUM(c.Gross_weight) + mut.tare_weight 
       from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_no =   mu.master_unit_no) END AS 'Total Weight'


from part_v_container c
```

So this should have fixed my part.  I do have an extra comment though.  You have all these different prefixs (p., c., mut., mu., g., pct.).  Where do you reference all of these?  I can see where you reference c (it is right after the final from).  Even in my part you use mut. but I don't know how you reference it.  For example, c is useable because of `from part_v_container c`.  c represents part_v_container. You can look into `joins` to help you get the other tables in there.  If you want you can edit your original question and add all your tables to it (whether they are actual or examples). I just need to know the different table names and column names.  I don't care about the actual data.  I wish I personally knew you because this would be much easier in real time xD

**EDIT 5**

Using this table...

[image]

I used this query...

```
;WITH mult AS (SELECT (m.length*0.0254)*(m.width*0.0254)*(m.height*0.0254) AS multiply, m.container FROM measurement m)
, sumMult AS (SELECT SUM((m.length*0.0254)*(m.width*0.0254)*(m.height*0.0254)) AS sumMultiply, m.container FROM measurement m GROUP BY m.container)
, combine AS (SELECT s.sumMultiply AS sumMultiply, m.multiply AS multiply, m.container FROM mult m JOIN sumMult s ON m.container = s.container)
SELECT c.container, CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.container ORDER BY c.container)) = 1 
   THEN (SELECT c.sumMultiply)

   ELSE (SELECT c.multiply)
END AS 'Cubic Meters'

FROM combine c GROUP BY c.container, c.sumMultiply, c.multiply
```

It SUMS all of the volumes for all parts in a container and displays it only in the first row (first part).  The rest of the parts have their volume.

I can't completely convert it for you.  I trust, since you have done it successfully in my previous queries, that you can convert it properly.  I tried to keep the names for the table and columns as bland and recognizable as much as I could.  It appears to be working how you want it.  Incase you don't know what the `;WITH mult....` is...you can think of it like a function.  Put the entire with statement (that is, mult, sumMult, combine) before your gigantic query.  You can see in my query that my `;WITH` is comes first (above) my SELECT query that produces the actual results.

Comment: Yes you get the jist of what I want and next time I will try to provide visual drawings.  Everything you said is correct but the problem is I have so many different container_id that to identify them all would be extremely time consuming.  Is there a way to identify them by their unique string value and only sum up parts for that unique string value?  Also what I meant by first occurrence is that there'll be multiple rows of the same container_id but i only want the weight to show on the first row in the output.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda I added an edit for you.  Hopefully it is what you want.  It sounded like you want something a little different where it still shows all the parts.  If you want me to do that and use the weight only on the first row I can just comment saying so.  You can go back to your original question and edit and add tables by the way:)

Comment: Thanks for the help cody, but im afraid its a little more complex so i made a screenshot to help you understand what I am talking about.  http://s33.postimg.org/3t63t83hr/sumweight.png shows one container with multiple parts and a weight on the first row.  Each of those parts has a weight.  I want to tally all those weights for each part and put it on the top row for every new container number.  Hopefully this makes sense.  I can share the code I've been trying.  Right not it just takes the first part's weight and not all the parts in the container.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda I think I finally got it!  I did what your picture is except I kept the part weight (which I can easily get rid of) and instead of blank spaces there are 0's because its an int (can use convert to use varchar or something).  just a heads up, to make it easier for everyone you could edit your question with that information so it is more easily viewed by everyone and I will either check back and see it or you could comment telling me you added a edit :)

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda oh just noticed you edited your main question.  Nevermind then!

Comment: Hey Cody I really appreciate the help man, you immediately solved the problem I was having with the first occurrence so I appreciate that.  I tried doing the query you gave me to select all the weights for the container but I get "Syntax error in SQL on line -1 symbol -1. Found 'end of input
Corresponding end keyword not found of: CASE(87,1)', expected 'Unknown'."  Is there a way to do it within a select query?

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda can you show me the exact query you were using? I assume you changed some things like the name. I'm currently out but when I get home I'll do more research for you. :)

Comment: Ok ill try to simplify this.  I am running a select query that takes many variables and sets them as columns.  Within I am trying to accumulate all parts from one container as a total weight for that container.  The code I used is: select c.*,
CASE WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
THEN select SUM(c.Gross_weight)+mut.tare_weight from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_no = mu.master_unit_no
END AS 'Total Weight' .  mu_master_unit is the M# (container number).  c.Gross_weight is the weight for the individual part.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda Try this...select c.*, CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 THEN (select SUM(c.Gross_weight)+mut.tare_weight from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_no = mu.master_unit_no) END AS 'Total Weight'   I believe the issue was that you were missing '(' at the start of the select and ')' at the end so it didn't see that the end you had was for the case

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda also you forgot something else I didn't notice..I will add it in my answer to make it more noticeable

Comment: I edited the original question with the code I am currently using.  Hopefully this helps, and I am still getting errors :(.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda It looks like you have some extra goodies :).  So to start off you do not need those asterisk I put in the code.  I put those there so you could see my change.  Also you have "select c.*" in the select display.  You do not need this.  You would either just do c.* by itself inside the select statement (like you did many other things) or do c.Column name.  An example you did was c.serial_no.  I will make an edit with your query changed.  If you still have an error afterword then please comment it.  I really want you to get it.  I am super determined.

Comment: I appreciate the support Cody.  Everything seems to be almost figured out, I just get this error now "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'M385028' to data type int".

Comment: So that error is exactly what it says.  The query is trying to convert that value to int.  Obviously you can't convert it to int since it has numbers.  I did a comparison.  I did a cast on a string and it came up with the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC123' to data type int.".  Much similar to yours.  I also did a comparison between non similar columns.  Error was "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  This is not as similar.  The first one sounds closer.  Try to find in the query where you would be converting.........

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda ....(look at previous question...did not add the @username)......the value 'M385028' to an int.  I would most likely guess it is happening inside a cast.  Did you update your query even further?  If you would like to update your query in your question I would love to look at it.  It is most likely converting inside a cast or trying to compare it and automatically converting it.  Quick question to help me help you.  Where would the value 'M385028' come up?  Is it the master_unit_no?

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  Apparently mu also had a master_unit_key variable which i could set the master_unit_key of c = too.  Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.  I have one little issue if you don't mind.  I am trying to do the same thing but, I want to sum up all the formulas I used to calculate the CBM.  I will edit the original post to my full code, but where I calculate the CBM I take 3 variables and multiply them together.  I want to take the sum of that equation for the M# CBM but it will not let me.  Says something about returning more than one value.

Comment: Actually if you don't mind I rather not have to make the idents on the full code lol.  The code I am using for the CBM is as follows:

,CASE
--WHEN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mu.master_unit_no ORDER BY mu.master_unit_no)) = 1 
--then (select sum((pct.cube_length*0.0254)*(pct.cube_width*0.0254)*(pct.cube_height*0.0254))
--from part_v_container c where c.master_unit_key = mu.master_unit_key)
when mu.master_unit_no is null
then (pct.cube_length*0.0254)*(pct.cube_width*0.0254)*(pct.cube_height*0.0254) 
end as 'CBM'

i commented out the non working code.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda I have a question.  What does the second 'when' do for you?  So one of your selects is producing more than one outcome when it only wants one.  An example of what I mean is if I did 'X = SELECT NUMBER FROM TABLE' then all numbers in the table will return and will not work.  Depending on what I want to do I would either do 'X IN SELECT NUMBER FROM TABLE' or 'X = SELECT NUMBER FROM TABLE WHERE NUMBER = 1' or something along the lines of that.  So even though I am a bit confused about your query it apparently got passed the intialization.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda so back to your error...one of your SELECTS is producing more than one outcome.  If you want to save you from time from typing anything you can quickly put a picture up in your original answer.  (prnt scrn, paste in paint, select area, copy, new paint, paste, save, post on stackoverflow).  And with your equation...is the pct.cube_length length of the parts or the container?  If it is the container then you only need to do the equation once, right? and not add anything?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: The second when takes the length,width,and height for the part times each by a number and times the results by eachother to get the cubic meters.  the length,width,and height are converted to meters, thus why i have them multipled by 0.0254.  The original measurement for them is in inches I believe.  Because the information is not stored as meters, I have to use the formula to get the individual part's size in meters for the total sum.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda so you want to take the sum of all of the volumes (which are in cubic meters) of all the parts for a specific container?  Looking into your query in more detail you have one SELECT.  What I want you to do it comment out the second WHEN sequence (that is everything that has to do with it) then run it.  Tell me the error if there is one.  Then I want you to uncomment out the second WHEN and comment out the first WHEN.  What I am having you do is try to minimize the source of the error.  There are two key parts (both of the WHENs)...lets check each individually.

Comment: There is no error and it executes if i comment out the whole case.  The way it is running now, with the first when statement commented out, a cbm shows for every part that is not in a M#.  That is what I want, but in addition I want a cbm to show up for every first instance of a m# and i want it to be the sum of all the cbms for every part in that m#.

Comment: I changed the code in the question to illustrate the calculating cbm case statement a little better.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda So we narrowed it down to where the issue is I believe.  You commented out the first WHEN and it works without error.  The error that you had previously usually (I am not sure if always) refers to a SELECT statement.  Your SELECT statement I believe is returning more than one value at a time.  I am going to run some tests and update you shortly.  If you want to look into your SELECT (inside the first WHEN) that would be good.

Comment: Thank you cody, I made a screenshot of the error when executing the full case statement.  http://s32.postimg.org/c4tlnq25x/cbm_error.png.  I am not sure why its returning more than one value.  It should be the sum of the all the calculated values.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda I believe I have the solution.  I will be making an edit to my answer.

Comment: Cody man sorry for wasting your time.  Apparently the length, width, and height of the M# were already given in the system.  I am sorry to have you go through all that extra work.  I really appreciate the help though man, I really don't know much about SQL so this really helped.  Thanks dude.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda Haha no problem.  One of the reasons I love helping people here because it is great practice for myself.  Is everything solved then?  If everything is good then you can set my answer as the answer.

Comment: Yeah its solved now.  How do I set your answer as the answer?

Comment: Nvm.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda no problem! It was fun.